# Spring RESTful Service URL to object

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

How can I convert a URL (http://127.0.0.1:8080/authors/1) to domain object?

I will let my clients submit URLs as foreign keys and I have to resolve them somehow.

For example I want to create a book with the author 1

```
POST /books
{"title":"Harry Potter", "author":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/authors/1"
```

I found a class named UriToEntityConverter that sounds right but of course 0 tutorials or examples.

I am serving my objects from a @RestController.

Comment: Maybe this test [UriToEntityConverterUnitTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/rest/core/UriToEntityConverterUnitTests.java) can help...

Answer (score 0):

you could simply define your path using request mapping and store the variable using pathVariable annotation

```
@RequestMapping(value="/authors/{id}", method=RequestMehtod.POST)
public RequestEntity<String> doSomething(@PathVariable("id") long id) //id will contain your id
```